# Can't seem to get started with Go and Echo

Tags: go, go-echo

Trying to build a simple crud api with Golang and Echo and I can't get past the first tep in the Echo docs.

I run `go get -u github.com/labstack/echo/...`

then I create server.go:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
)

func main() {
    e := echo.New()
    e.GET("/", func(c echo.Context) error {
        return c.String(http.StatusOK, "Hello, World!")
    })
    e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":1323"))
}
```

but when I try to run: `go run server.go`

I get this error:

```
server.go:6:2: cannot find package "github.com/labstack/echo/v4" in any of:
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.14.4/libexec/src/github.com/labstack/echo/v4 (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/dariusgoore/go/src/github.com/labstack/echo/v4 (from $GOPATH)
```

Comment: Run `go get github.com/labstack/echo/v4` as described in [the installation instructions](https://github.com/labstack/echo#guide).

Comment: Returns the same error message: cannot find package "github.com/labstack/echo/v4" in any of:
 /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.14.4/libexec/src/github.com/labstack/echo/v4 (from $GOROOT)
 /Users/dariusgoore/go/src/github.com/labstack/echo/v4 (from $GOPATH)

Comment: @user2799827 enable modules.  See [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) if you are new to writing Go code.

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable `GO111MODULE`. To enable the module you need to run this command.

```
export GO111MODULE=on
```

After enabling it when you will run `go run server.go` then it will install the packages again after that the program will run as expected.

Comment: trying that, getting now: cannot find module providing package github.com/labstack/echo/v4: working directory is not part of a module

Comment: Run command `go env` and see what's the value for `GO111MODULE`?

Answer (score 2):

I get the same issue when I run `go get` before `go mod init`. Using the following commands, I can run the server successfully:

```
go mod init example.com/try-echo
go get
go run server.go
```

Answer (score 0):

I just created a new project with the same main.go and it ran without any issue. I have listed the steps I followed.

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
)

func main() {
    e := echo.New()
    e.GET("/", func(c echo.Context) error {
        return c.String(http.StatusOK, "Hello, World!")
    })
    e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":1323"))
}
```

and used go.mod for dependencies downloads

`go mod init`

`go get`

`go run main.go`

and it ran without any error

```
       ____    __
  / __/___/ /  ___
 / _// __/ _ \/ _ \
/___/\__/_//_/\___/ v4.1.16
High performance, minimalist Go web framework
https://echo.labstack.com
____________________________________O/_______
                                    O\
⇨ http server started on [::]:1323
```

I hope this helps. If it doesn't you can run `go env` and share the result of the command, which will help to debug further.

Answer (score 0):

```
export GO111MODULE=on
go mod init
go mod tidy
```

if not succed, add more command:

```
go mod download
```